With Serde, how to capture arbitrary value with a custom data format deserializer?
I'm trying to write a deserializer for a custom data format in Rust using Serde according to this documentation.
Everything seems to work, except that I'd like to be able to capture part of the input in order to deserialize it later according to fields that have been deserialized in the first pass.
The serde_json crate provides a RawValue for this use case but I didn't find any documentation to support it in a custom deserializer.
How is it working? What should be the steps to implement an equivalent for a custom data format?

I don't really understand what you want to do, but from what I do understand, it seems like serde is not a good choice. In serde, everything has to be generic. This means you can't access the raw input in the Deserialize implementation.

In the first stage, parse the input as a string or vec whichever is appropriate for your use case. Then in the second stage do whatever you want with the "raw" data. How well this works is going to depend on how 'custom' your custom format is.

A "raw value" that leaks the underlying data format from the deserializer isn't defined in the Serde data model, so for serde-json to support it requires some trickery.
When a serde-json RawValue is deserialized, it advertises itself as newtype struct named $serde_json::private::RawValue (source):
pub const TOKEN: &str = "$serde_json::private::RawValue";

impl<'de: 'a, 'a> Deserialize<'de> for &'a RawValue {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        ...
        deserializer.deserialize_newtype_struct(TOKEN, ...)
    }
}

And in the serde-json Deserializer, when it deserializes newtype structs, it handles that name differently (source):
fn deserialize_newtype_struct<V: Visitor<'de>>(self, name: &str, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value> {
    if name == crate::raw::TOKEN {
        return self.deserialize_raw_value(visitor);
    }

    visitor.visit_newtype_struct(self)
}

From there, it ends up passing the raw value to the RawValue through its visitor implementation as if it looked like { "$serde_json::private::RawValue": "the raw input" }. This is likely because deserialize_newtype_struct is expected to be handled as a "map". You can look in the source through the implementations for ReferenceVisitor, RawKey, and ReferenceFromString for the specifics. Slightly different types exist for Box<RawValue> - I've only linked those for &RawValue.
As evident, serde-json's RawValue only really works with serde-json's Deserializer since it requires this workaround. If you are making your own custom data format and want to support "raw values" then you will want to mimic the above steps.
